# Why does gcc have a warning for long long?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, types, gcc-warning

What is the reason for the `-Wlong-long` gcc warning?

From the gcc man page:

```
-Wlong-long
       Warn if long long type is used.  This is enabled by either -Wpedantic or -Wtraditional in ISO C90 and C++98 modes.  To inhibit the warning messages, use -Wno-long-long.
```

As I understand it, `long long` is required to be at least 64-bits (practically it is always 64-bits, at least with today's compilers).  Was this not the case for ISO C90 or C++98, or is there some other reason not to use `long long`?

I know about `<stdint.h>` types like `int64_t` and friends, but some not-so-old compilers (e.g. VS2005, and Green Hills ARM 3.5) do not provide `<stdint.h>`, and I thought `long long` would be (at least) 64 bits for those and newer toolchains.

Comment: Compilers that don't have `stdint.h` are not C99-compliant, which means there are good odds they don't have `long long` at all!  (Unless they're old versions of GCC.)

Comment: From the description given it sounds like Patrick's "not-so-old" compilers are in the same category as a 90's gcc - `long long` without `stdint.h` (except that through most of the 90's we had the excuse that C99 wasn't written yet, plus the excuse that "ordinary" CPUs didn't have 64-bit integer registers, so the lack of a 64-bit integer among the basic C types made some sense.)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: C was designed to be usable (and in the 1980s was in fact often used) on 8-bit processors; having to perform long additions in four steps was somewhat irksome, but even when numbers were known to be no greater than 16777215 the convenience of being able to operate on a single quantity was worth the performance drain of using four steps rather than three.  There are far fewer cases where using an 8-byte type would be justifiable.  IMHO, the proper remedy would have been to make "long long" an optional feature, at least for freestanding implementations.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There was no `long long` type yet in ISO C90 and C++98. It has only been added in ISO C99 and C++11.

GCC provided it as an extension prior to standardization, though.

Comment: ...a rare example of a gcc extension that became standardized with the same semantics

Comment: So the reason to provide such a warning would appear to be to help ensure your code compiles with non C99- or C++-11-compliant compilers.

Comment: @Patrick yes, and I think the option only exists because someone decided that all of the warnings enabled by `-ansi -pedantic` should be represented by their own `-Wfoo` options. There's really no reason to use `-Wlong-long` on its own. Oh, but `-Wno-long-long` does make more sense.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I thought there was no way to specifically disable some `-pedantic` warnings, such as the warning about superfluous semicolons. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Patrick: Another reason for such a warning, for decimal literals that happen to be between LNG_MAX+1u and ULNG_MAX is that such literals are regarded as unsigned types in C89, but signed types in C99.  In C89 implementations where LNG_MAX is 2147483647 and ULNG_MAX is 4294967295, the expression `4294967295==-1` would yield 1 (since both sides would be converted to `unsigned long`), while in C99 it would evaluate to 0 (both sides converted to `unsigned long long`).

Comment: I would add an up vote, but 32 is such a nice number!

Comment: @Galaxy long long is at least **64**-bit though. ;)